# Grid css placement with weird html structure

Tags: css

HTML structure:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="third">
         <div class="fourth"></div>
         <div class="fifth">
              <div class="sixth"></div>
              <div class="seventh"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On a grid of 4x4 (4 rows x 4 columns) I want to create a grid where:

```
.second is on 1x1 , 1x2 , 2x1, 2x2 position
.fourth is on 1x3 , 1x4 , 2x3, 2x4 position
.fifth is on 3x1, 3x2 , 3x3, 3x4,  4x1, 4x2 , 4x3, 4x4 position
.sixth is on 3x1, 3x2,  3x3, 3x4  position
.seventh is on 4x3, 4x4 position
```

So I could get something like this:

[image: Grid wanted]

```
.div1 in the image is .second
.div2 in the image is .fourth
.div3 in the image is .sixth
.div4 in the image is .seventh
```

Is this possible with grid or flexbox?

Comment: It's possible with grid. Have you tried anything yet? This is a pretty simple grid setup, but not with your markup. If your `third` element is wrapping everything, there's no way to get it to wrap like this. Also, update your question with the **actual** classes instead of telling us what is assigned to what. Currently your HTML and CSS don't match the classes in your image.

Comment: This can be done with [subgrid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid). However, it's support isn't the greatest at the moment

Comment: What happened to .fifth? Please edit your question so the problem is stated and illustrated consistently. This is important as display: contents may or may not be helpful here.

Comment: @AHaworth, my apologies, tried hard tonight got late and I went to sleep, fifth doesn't really matter, since sixth and seventh is on the right position.

Comment: In that case you could simplify the code in my answer by having .fifth also display: contents and adding div3 and div4 into the initial grid-template-areas.

Comment: @AHaworth Ah okay, I thought it needed somehow, thats why I put it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get .third 'ignored' by the grid placements by giving it display: contents. Its direct children, rather than it, then get considered for placement in the grid.

Then to get the children of .fifth placed you need to make .fifth a grid in its own right.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
  grid-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: 'div1 div1 div2 div2' 'div1 div1 div2 div2' 'div5 div5 div5 div5' 'div5 div5 div5 div5';
}

.parent * {
  border: solid white 1px;
}

.third {
  display: contents;
}

.second {
  background: brown;
  grid-area: div1;
}

.fourth {
  background: teal;
  grid-area: div2;
}

.sixth {
  background: green;
  grid-area: div3;
}

.seventh {
  background: green;
  grid-area: div4;
}

.fifth {
  background: navy;
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
  grid-row: 3 / span 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: 'div3 div3 div3 div3' 'blank blank div4 div4';
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third">
    <div class="fourth"></div>
    <div class="fifth">
      <div class="sixth"></div>
      <div class="seventh"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Learnt a lot from this example, but noticed that  aspect-ratio, grid-column and grid-rows doesn't seem right for the browsers, is there any explanation? why not use grid-template-columns?

Comment: You are right, grid-rows etc should be grid-template-rows etc but in this case grid areas were used. aspect-ratio was simply to give a height that looked similar to the sort of height you showed in relation to the width. You may be setting height a different way (but you didn’t show us the relevant code so I had to set height to something)